# Kubernetes: run container as a root

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, root, kubernetes-pod, security-context

I do understand [drawbacks](https://dev.to/techworld_with_nana/run-pod-with-root-privileges-41n9) of doing this, however I have image that will work only with root user running cmd within it.

Server kubernetes version is: `v1.19.14`.
Inside my `deployment.yaml` I have:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        runAsUser: 0
      command: ...
      image:...
```

But when I `describe rs` I see following:

```
  Type     Reason        Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------        ----               ----                   -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  0s (x13 over 21s)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "myapp-7cdd994c56-" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 0: running with the root UID is forbidden]
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try creating a ad-hoc pod(without replicaset or deployment) with same image and security context as you posted above. If this work, but not with rs/deployment then it means ,your the rs controller is not having proper rolebinding to work with psp. Try creating a role binding to use the psp for the default SA of your namespace.

Comment: @P...., I run into the same issue when test it against pure Pod.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ How is cluster set up? Is it cloud or on-prem? Also are there any `PodSecurityPolicy`s? Can be checked with `kubectl get PodSecurityPolicy`

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 0: running with the root UID is forbidden]

***Pod Security Policy*** is defined in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/) as:

> [...] a cluster-level resource that controls security sensitive aspects of the pod specification. The PodSecurityPolicy objects define a set of conditions that a pod must run with in order to be accepted into the system [...]

You are using a cluster for which the Pod Security Policy forbids the use of root containers (See [Pod Security Policy - Users and Groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/#users-and-groups))

You have to change the Pod Security Policy yourself or ask your cluster administrator to do so.

Note that:

> PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated as of Kubernetes v1.21, and will be removed in v1.25.